# android adding table rows with an array

Tags: java, android, xml, view, row

I'm currently using a list view but that isn't going to work for me so I'm wanting achieve the same effect using a table view and rows. for example I have a json feed and with news stories and for every news story create a row that has a image and textview  and fill it with the data from the json.

So my question is does anyone know of a way on how I could do this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

   <include layout="@layout/header" />
   <include layout="@layout/redcell" />

   <TableRow

       android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="100dp" >


      <TextView

        android:id="@+id/fixtures_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/leagues"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>




   </TableRow>

   <include layout="@layout/redcell" />

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="100dp" >


      <TextView

        android:id="@+id/_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/leagues"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

   </TableRow>

    <include layout="@layout/redcell" />
```

activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String apiKey = "67htj4455jsd345jj956id"; 
    private static final String apiUser = "android";
    private static final String ChosenTeam = null;
    private static String ChosenMethod = null; 
    public String fulldata = null;
    public String chosenLeagueId = "40";
    public List<String> newsList = null;
    public int newsAmount = 0;
    private static final String ChosenMethodPref = null;





    long unixTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

    //add Time Stamp to URL


    //public String chosenMethod; 


    String newsFeedRequest = "1.0/website/" + chosenLeagueId + "/news?timestamp=" + unixTimeStamp;
    String fixturesFeedURL = "https://www.example.com/_services/api/" + newsFeedRequest;


    private static String buildHmacSignature(String pKey, String pStringToSign)
    {
      String lSignature = "None";
      try
      {
        Mac lMac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec lSecret = new SecretKeySpec(pKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        lMac.init(lSecret);

        byte[] lDigest = lMac.doFinal(pStringToSign.getBytes());
        BigInteger lHash = new BigInteger(1, lDigest);
        lSignature = lHash.toString(16);
        if ((lSignature.length() % 2) != 0) {
          lSignature = "0" + lSignature;
        }
      }
      catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException lEx)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problems calculating HMAC", lEx);
      }
      catch (InvalidKeyException lEx)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problems calculating HMAC", lEx);
      }

      return lSignature;
    }


    public void checkPreferences(){


        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String ChosenMethodPref = preferences.getString("ChosenMethod", ChosenMethod);
        Log.v("myapp", "ChosenMethod Home = " + ChosenMethodPref);

         if (ChosenMethodPref.equals("Team")) {
             setContentView(R.layout.homeactteam);
             newsAmount = 5;
             TextView redHeaderText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.redheadertext);
             redHeaderText.setText("Latest League Fixture");



         } else {
             setContentView(R.layout.homeact);
             newsAmount = 10;

         }

}
    public void loadData(){String myhash = buildHmacSignature(apiKey, fixturesFeedURL);





    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(fixturesFeedURL);

    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestToken", myhash));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiUser", apiUser));

    try {
        post.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();
        fulldata = String.valueOf(json);
        Log.v("myApp","newsdata" + fulldata);
        newsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);    
        JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("news");


           for(int t = 0; t < newsAmount; t++){
               JSONObject newsTitleDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);


               newsList.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));

           }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList));

       ListView list = getListView();

        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



    }   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        checkPreferences();
        loadData();


        Button backbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbtn);

        //Listening to button event
        backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent previousScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChooseTeamActivity.class);
                ChosenMethod = "null";
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("ChosenMethod", ChosenMethod);            
                editor.commit();
                previousScreen.putExtra("FullData", fulldata);
                startActivity(previousScreen);


            }
        });




    }











@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {

        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));

        return(true);
  }


    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.match) {

        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MatchActivity.class));

        return(true);
  }



    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.teams) {

        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, TeamsActivity.class));

        return(true);
  }



    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.twitter) {

        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, TwitterActivity.class));

        return(true);
  }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.info) {

        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, InfoActivity.class));

        return(true);
  }


    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));


}



}
```

Comment: You have not mentioned your problem/Question or Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter as the Adapter used by your ListActivity. In the getView() method of that custom adapter, you can load the image and the text for each item in your newsList.

A simple LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation would probably work best for the row layout in your custom adapter. If you set the layout_weight of your TextView to 1 and leave the image without a layout_weight, that will push your image to one side of the row.